# Ces phrases sont grammaticalement correctes et habituelles ?

Tags: grammaire

Objet : Demande de correction d'une erreur sur l'attestation

Chère directrice,

J'ai le plaisir de savoir que ma demande d’admission au Foyer International a été acceptée. J'ai bien reçu l'attestation aussi. Cependant, sur l'attestaion, mon nom est incorrectement indiqué comme monsieur, pas madame. Cela peut être un problème lors du processus de délivrance de mon visa. Je suis désolée, mais pourriez-vous bien vouloir me renvoyer l'attestation en la modifiant avec madame ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Here is for staters: never "Chère directrice," but instead "Madame la directrice,".

Comment: Better to use [chat] for such questions. You just need 20 reputation points to be able to post there.